# How to wait for a MediaPlayer to complete a Position change

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to use an invisible MediaPlayer to generate thumbnails at specific time positions in a video

I've tried waiting on the player's dispatcher thread with `_player.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle, new Action(() => { })).Wait();`
 but that didn't seem to make any difference. It works with a long enough wait on the thread, but I don't like using an arbitrary number.

```cs
        private MediaPlayer _player;

        private void Player_MediaOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
            TimeSpan duration = _player.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan;
            TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan();
            TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1); // One Second
            RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(160, 90, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            while (time < duration)
            {
                _player.Position = time;
                Thread.Sleep(10); // This is the line I'm unhappy about!
                Application.Current?.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action(() => { })).Wait(); // Wait for the UI to catch up so you see all the images as they are being rendered
                using (DrawingContext dc = dv.RenderOpen())
                {
                    dc.DrawVideo(_player, new Rect(0, 0, 160, 90));
                }
                bmp.Render(dv);
                Image thumbImage = new Image()
                {
                    Width = 160,
                    Height = 90
                };
                thumbImage.Source = bmp.GetAsFrozen() as ImageSource;
                thumbnailsPanel.Children.Add(thumbImage);
                time = time.Add(interval);
            }
            _player.Close();
        }
```

With the `Thead.sleep(10);` it works correctly but I'm uncomfortable with an arbirary pause. I'd like to wait until the `MediaPlayer` has completed `_player.Position = time;`. If `Thead.sleep(10);` is reduced to, say, 1ms, then the images produced are incorrect - they show earlier frames instead of the actual ones.

Does anyone know how to wait until the `MediaPlayer` has finished this asynchronous operation?

Comment: Use async await and Task.Run , then use Task.Delay(ms) instead of Thread.sleep.